# Firefox is blocking fetch requests on same origin

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm a little stumped with this one, I'm making a request in firefox to a relative url:

```
await fetch('/foo/bar',{});
```

This errors out with:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Furthermore, the urls show up as 'blocked' in the network tab:

[image]

Things I've checked:

- uBlock origin is off
- Tracking protection is off
- Server is running, the request succeeds when I directly open it in my browser, or via CURL.
- This is not related to CORS, as the origins are all local.

Comment: Maybe has something quirky to do with the cert you're using to host localhost:8531 over https? You could rule that out by instead trying to host over http and use something like ngrok to tunnel over https with a non-localhost domain...just something to try. Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: What are the headers?

Comment: Did you somehow accidentally mark it to be blocked?

Comment: @dwosk I'm actually just using plain http everywhere, no https

Comment: @epascarello no special headers, the `fetch()` request just uses the first URI parameter. I checked the Web developer tools block list, and it doesn't appear there.

Comment: are you running your frontend on a different port from your backend? If so, that could result in a CORS error even if both are using the same localhost domain. Might need to pass some additional headers from your server.

Comment: I think I have the answer to this, will answer myself shortly. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @dwosk / epascarello thank you for the help. Turns out I'm just a dummy. Answered my own question below.

Comment: Nice - FWIW I found this Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1280189. I guess you found what was causing the redirection.

Comment: @dwosk wow good find! Exactly what I ran into.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue.

1. The `fetch()` request was initiated.
2. An unrelated error was thrown.
3. This error was not checked correctly, causing the browser to redirect to a different url.
4. This redirect caused the (still running) fetch request to abort.
5. The aborted request shows up as a `block`, setting me on an incorrect path to try and fix this.

So things were broken, just not where I expected. Thank you for helping me think and find the root cause